# After changing item in Sharepointlist, everyone in flow gets e-mailed

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have a sharepoint list with several items and a flow.

I have different conditions: 
If Phonenumber is set to true, send email to A.
If Car is set to true, send email to B.
And so on.

Wel every time i change a item, for example, i change Phonenumber to true in one item and Car remains true, also B is emailed. I would like it that only A is mailed since only that field is changed.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we don't have similar functionality to easily monitor how the specified field values have changed.

At present, what we can achieve is to use version to monitor whether the specified field value has changed. By comparing the value of the previous version of the item with the value of the current version, it is judged whether the value of the specified field has changed.

Please check this blog and see if it helps:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Check-for-a-Change-in-a-SharePoint-List-Column-Value/bc-p/248270#M503

Also if you want similar features to be supported by MS Flow, please consider voting for similar ideas:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Ideas/Modified-trigger-should-give-previous-values-for-fields-changed/idi-p/94078/page/3#comments

Similar issue:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Create-Flow-to-Send-Email-When-SharePoint-List-Column-Changes/td-p/403219

Answer (score 0):

Try to

- Create separate flows. One will fire and send email to A when Phonenumber will be changed to true. The second will fire and send email to B when Car will be changed to true.

or

- Add IF statement to compare previous version of listitem with current version and do the staff in case of something was changed